# Docker Server Error : request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version

Tags: docker, error-handling, build, dockerfile, command-line-interface

Internal server error on docker CLI

```
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json, check if the server supports the requested API version
```

When trying

```
docker ps
```

or

```
docker version
```

I get errors from the server (no error for client detail)

Currently running docker 24.0.7 and not sure what to do because this error is also freezing my docker desktop so I can't run it.

I have tried uninstalling.

Comment: Could you please share:
1. How you installed docker?
2. Which operating system you're using? (i.e. linux, macos or WSL)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after I upgraded docker desktop to 4.28.0 in windows 10 machine. My fix is to uninstall docker desktop then install 4.27.2.